# Django not Redirecting due to Page not Found Error

Tags: python, django

I am creating an edit profile function that updates the profile and redirects back to the profile page of the current user. Currently, the updating works fine, but the redirection is giving me a page not found error. Why is that happening?

url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('change-profile/', users_views.change_profile, name='change_profile'),
    path('user/<str:username>/', UserProfileView.as_view(), name='user-profile'),
    ...
]
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def change_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile Updated')
            return redirect('user-profile', {'username':request.user.username})
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'u_form' : u_form,
        'p_form' : p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/change_profile.html', context)
```

Error message[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`redirect(…)`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) uses *named parameters*, not a dictionary, so:

```
return redirect('user-profile', username=request.user.username)
```

You have sent `{'username': 'TestPWRS' }` as username, and (likely) there is no user with that username, only a user with username `TestPWRS`.